# Show image in browser in full screen in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, image, browser, fullscreen

i want to show an image in the browser page and to stretch it so it would fill the whole browser page.

i tried:

```
<asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/mypic.jpg" Width="100%" Height="100%"></asp:Image>
```

and also tried using css:

```
<asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/mypic.jpg"  CssClass="myimage1"></asp:Image>
```

and in the CSS:

.myimage1{height:100%;width:100%;}

in both cases the browser (IE9), stretches the image with a height that is much bigger then the broswer hight and a right scroll bar is shown.

How can i stretch an image to the exact size of the current page size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution using an img html tag and using CSS:
http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/850635-how-stretch-background-image-fill

add this inside the aspx page inside the body tag:

```
<img src="Styles/mypic.jpg" alt="" />
```

in the css:

```
html,body 
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

img
{
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its stretching to 100% of the parent container, which might be too wide.  Try setting the width value of the body and html elements.

Try setting

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Or you could use jQuery to find out the width of the parent element first and then set your image to that.  No need to use ASP controls with this, just CSS and jquery.

```
$newheight = $('#yourimageid').parent().height();
$('#yourimageid').css('height', $newheight);
```

This will grab the parent elements height, and then append the value to the css height value